# How can I get access to Hijikata's mimeographed notes?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups

In several papers on buildings, Hijikata's mimeographed notes from Yale ("Maximal compact subgroups of some p-adic classical groups") are often cited as a precursor to the work of Bruhat-Tits. While Bruhat-Tits is freely available, I cannot find Hijikata's notes. I looked at WorldCat and it appears that there are only two universities in the world that have it: Yale and Institut Henri Poincare. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you could try the "request scan" link in the [Worldcat entry](http://orbis.library.yale.edu/vwebv/search?searchCode=GKEY%5E*&recCount=50&searchType=1&searchArg=ocm54200626)

Comment: I need a Yale ID to do that.

Comment: Do you have access to a university library? They might be able to get a copy for you or can at least tell you how to proceed.

Comment: I don't have those notes (perhaps Paul Garrett does?), but I did review a 1975 paper based on his 1968 Tokyo thesis: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0498886.   The English is fairly rough, but it does indicate how his thinking at the time overlapped the work of Bruhat-Tits and others.